# How can fix NameError: global name is not defined error in python?

Tags: python, global-variables, multiprocessing, shared-memory, python-multiprocessing

I wrote this python code for multiplying 2 matrices using threads.but I gave this error:

```
    raise self._value
NameError: global name 'A' is not defined.
```

I know it's because of defining global A,B matrices but I'm new in python and I don't know how to fix it.
how can I fix this problem?

```
import numpy
import random
import numpy as np
from random import randint
import multiprocessing, numpy, ctypes

def lineMult(start):
    #global A, B, C, part
    n = len(A)
    for i in xrange(start, start+part):
        for k in xrange(n):
            for j in xrange(n):
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j]

def creationthreads(A, B, threadNumber):
    n = len(A)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(threadNumber)
    pool.map(lineMult, range(0,n, part))
    return C

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse, sys
    from argparse import ArgumentParser

    temp=[]
    #initializing matrices------------------
    size = int(raw_input('Enter n: '))
    print('initializing A...')
    A = []
    for i in range (0, size):
        new = []
        for j in range (0, size):
            new.append(randint(-1000,1000))
        A.append(new)
    print ('matrice A initialized with:    ',A)

    print('initializing B...')
    B = []
    for i in range (0, size):
        new = []
        for j in range (0, size):
            new.append(randint(-1000,1000))
        B.append(new)
    print ('matrice B initialized with:    ',B)

    # #finish initializing matrices

    threadNumber = 2
    part=size / threadNumber
    if part < 1:
        part = 1
    temp= creationthreads(A, B, threadNumber)
```

Comment: You are using multi*processing*, not multi*threading*. Globals are not so easily shared between multiple processes. Read [*Sharing State*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) carefully.

Comment: @MartijnPieters. thank you so much for your help.yes you're right.I had mistake to tell that I'm using multiprogramming.and I read page you said about shared memory and I got that I should use a shared memory for the result of multiplication .but I still have the problem I said above.do you know how can I fix that

Comment: Again, you cannot share globals. Don't use globals to share state.

Comment: Note: `global A` does not actually create a global variable `A`. It simply declares that, in this function, we want to use the global variable `A` rather than creating a local one. The global variable needs to already exist...